# Grunt-scaffold after() function access to prompt answers

Tags: javascript, node.js, build, gruntjs, scaffolding

[The docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-scaffold) for the NPM package `grunt-scaffold` lacked any information really on its `after()` property/function.. I have a grunt file which creates a new directory for a new script and copies boilerplate files into it from the designated template folder.. The desire is to finish the `grunt scaffold:new_script` command and have it log out the location of the newly generated folder.

**Gruntfile.js**

```
  module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
  scaffold: {
    new_script: {
        options: {
            questions: [{
                name: 'script_name',
                type: 'input',
                message: 'Script name, catterpillar_case?(e.g. \'new_script\'):'
            }],
            template: {
                "scripts/etl_template/": "scripts/{{script_name}}/",
            },
            after: function(){

                console.log("New script generated in new folder scripts/{{script_name}}")
            }
        }
      }
    }
  });
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-scaffold');
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['scaffold']);
};
```

However, the ouput is

```
-bash-4.1$ grunt scaffold:new_script
Running "scaffold:new_script" (scaffold) task
? Script name, catterpillar_case?(e.g. 'new_script'): test_grunt
New script generated in new folder scripts/{{script_name}}
Done.
```

This did not do the string replacing as it did when it created the `scripts/test_grunt` folder! As you can see [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-scaffold) almost doesn't exist for that after() functionality, and I'm wondering if I can use javascript"system argume

Answer (score 0):

An example was not given in the documentation for the `after()` function, but if you use the same result parameter as in the example given for `filter()`, you can access the answer values via their names.

**Gruntfile.js**

```
  module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
  scaffold: {
    new_script: {
        options: {
            questions: [{
                name: 'script_name',
                type: 'input',
                message: 'Script name, catterpillar_case?(e.g. \'new_script\'):'
            }],
            template: {
                "scripts/etl_template/": "scripts/{{script_name}}/",
            },
            after: function(result){
                console.log("New script generated in new folder scripts/" + result.script_name)
            }
        }
      }
    }
  });
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-scaffold');
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['scaffold']);
};
```

**Output**

```
-bash-4.1$ grunt scaffold:new_script
Running "scaffold:new_script" (scaffold) task
? Script name, catterpillar_case?(e.g. 'new_script'): test_grunt
New script generated in new folder scripts/test_grunt
Done.
```